# QuickSort on CircularDoublyLinkedListed

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I try to write method for 
public void quicksort(DListNode start, DListNode end)

for a class CDLinkedList (which is circular doubly linked list)

this method can sort a list or part of the list. (Inclusively start and end)

And here is what I wrote.
I don't know whether is this correct and is it efficient enough for the average case run time ?
Is there any other way or this is already good ?

```
class DListNode{
int data;
DListNode nextNode, previousNode;

DListNode(int data){
    this.data = data;
    this.nextNode = this.previousNode = null;
}}
```

.

```
public class CDLinkedList{
DListNode header;
int size;
static final int HEADERVALUE = -9999999;

public CDLinkedList(){
    size = 0;
    header = new DListNode(HEADERVALUE);
    makeEmpty();
}

public void makeEmpty(){
    header.nextNode = header;
    header.previousNode = header;
}

public void quickSort(DListNode start, DListNode end){
    if(start == end)
        return;
    if(start == this.header)
        start = header.nextNode;
    if(end == this.header)
        end = header.previousNode;

    DListNode startnext = start;    //use for left portion
    DListNode endnext = end;        //use for right portion

    int first, last;
    first = start.data;
    DListNode pivot = end;          
    end = end.previousNode;     
    last = end.data;                

    while(true){                    //Since it is LinkedList. start and end will never cross each other
        while(start!=end){
            if(start.data>=pivot.data)
                break;
            start = start.nextNode;
        }

        while(end!=start){
            if(end.data<=pivot.data)
                break;
            end = end.previousNode;
        }

        int temp = start.data;
        start.data = end.data;
        end.data = temp;

        if(start == end){
            if(start.data>pivot.data){
            temp = start.data;
            start.data = pivot.data;
            pivot.data = temp;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pivot!=startnext)
        this.quickSort(startnext, end );
    if(pivot!=endnext)
        this.quickSort(end.nextNode, endnext);  
}
```

}

Comment: This will have worst case runtime on already sorted lists, but otherwise looks fine. Write some tests and see if it works well.

Comment: A bottom up merge sort using a small (26 to 32 entries) array of pointers (references in the case of Java) is the normal way to sort a linked list. Take a look at the wiki article for [linked list merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .

Comment: I'm just curious what if I try to find the middle index of the List at first, then compare to find the median of first, middle, and last. Take the median to be the pivot.
Will that worsen the runtime ? or will it be better ?

Comment: The issue is scanning a linked list to emulate indexing is inefficient. This is why some variation of bottom up merge sort is better for linked lists.